# How to read a Multiframe Dicom file and display it as video using an UI

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt, pydicom, simpleitk

I am looking to find a way to read a DICOM file and display the multi frame DICOM file as a video in an UI, I tried reading the multi frame DICOM file using pydicom and I was able to get each frame and appended it into a list and I created a gif out of that multi frame DICOM file and used the tkinter to display the gif in the UI. As you can see I was storing the multi frame as gif locally and display it. I want to know is there any other way without storing the frame as gif, read the frame and display it directly in an UI. Below is the code which I used

```
from tkinter import *


lisImage = []

if __name__=="__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument("dicom_image", help="Path to the DICOM image to load")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    import imageio

    index=0;
    frameCnt = 243
    root = Tk()
    
    frames = [PhotoImage(file='movie.gif', format='gif -index %i' % (i)) for i in range(frameCnt)]


    def update(ind):

        frame = frames[ind]
        ind += 1
        if ind == frameCnt:
            ind = 0
        label.configure(image=frame)
        root.after(100, update, ind)


    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    root.after(0, update, 0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For SimpleITK's Show function, we use Fiji/imageJ do display a volume. In Fiji you can make it play the 3d volume as a 2d animation.

Comment: @DaveChen can you provide some sample , which helps me in understanding how it works